# Open cover of compact sets by linked balls

Tags: general-topology

**Question** is it true the following statement?

If $K$ is a compact set contained in the *connected* open subset $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, then there exists an
open cover of $K$ consisting of finitely many balls $(B_i)_{i = 0}^m$ strictly contained
in $\Omega$, such that the center of the ball $B_{i}$ belongs to $B_{i+1}$.

Comment: I wish the people who downvote questions like this would explain why they do...

Comment: Thanks @Cronus :-)

Comment: Consider a starfish shaped region that contains 5 line segments joining at the center of the shape. Does this say No to your question?

Comment: Maybe I get what you have in mind. Since I am not sure, let me try to ask you the following question: Does the possibility to pass many times along the same path let you change your mind?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you copied the question wrong? This formulation seems odd to me.

The answer is yes otherwise, and here's a proof. Fix a point $p\in\Omega$, and consider the balls $B_i$ around $p$ of radius $i$ for $i=1,2,3,4...$. The union of all these balls cover all of $\Bbb{R}^n$, and in particular it covers $K$. Therefore, there is a finite sub-cover $\{B_1,...,B_m\}$, since $K$ is compact. The centre of $B_{i+1}$ is contained in $B_i$, since all the balls have the same centre.

But in fact each ball contains the previous ball, so we found *one* single ball which covers $K$ - namely, $B_m$. This is why it seems to me that perhaps your formulation is wrong... (I have no idea why someone downvoted the question, though).

**EDIT**. My original answer was wrong. I have another idea - it's not completely formal yet, but I think it should work.

Cover $K$ with finitely many balls strictly contained in $\Omega$. This is easy: just take around each point in $K$ a ball strictly contained in $\Omega$, and take a subcover.

Now, we have finitely many balls $B_1,...,B_m$ all strictly contained in $\Omega$ and whose union covers $K$. Take a path $\phi:[0,1]\to\Omega$ which intersects $B_1$ and then $B_2$ and so forth until $B_m$. I think it shouldn't be hard to prove this can be done; since $\Omega$ is open and connected, it is path connected, so we can find a path from any point in $B_1$ to any point in $B_2$, and from $B_2$ to $B_3$, and so forth, and the concatenate these paths and call it $\phi$.

Now, we just need to take a lot of balls along $\phi$ and add them to our list. This part is really not formal, but I think it shouldn't be hard to formulate it rigorously.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that these balls are not strictly contained in $\Omega$. By this I mean that the closures of these ball should be subsets of $\Omega$. PS Yes two people voted negatively the question. I don't know why.

Comment: @Kosh Oh, I missed that requirement! Sorry. This is a very interesting question... Where is from? Is it from a book?

Comment: Nope, I realized that can be used to simplify the proof of a result. Well, provided is simpler to prove this than the original problem. But nevertheless, even if more complicated I prefer complicated proofs of clear results than average proofs of not clear intermediate results. I think that the question has a positive answer, but the proof I have in mind takes some time to be written down with all details. So I was hoping in someone that could give a simple proof of this (I guess based on refinements) because he already had to solve a similar question.

Comment: I see. What if we take $K=\{0,3\}$ and $\Omega=(-1,1)\cup(2,4)$. Isn't that a counterexample?

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing out that I forgot to write that $\Omega$ has to be connected. I will edit the question. Anyhow, let me tell the idea, hoping it will not bias who is reading. One considers an open $\epsilon$ neighborhood of the compact set. Then a countable family of parallel lines which slice the compact set, and with distances less then (to be safe) $\epsilon/4$. Then one builds linked balls along these lines...

Comment: @Kosh Yeah I imagined you forgot to write something like this. This is very cool, I'll have to think about it. I'm not deleting my answer so as not to delete these comments.

Comment: @Kosh Hi, I edited my answer and tried again. There are some technical details to work through but I think it should work and that the idea is simple.

Comment: Good to know you believe the result to be true :-). However, that's the direction I would like to avoid because one has to take care of many things in this "snake" construction.

Comment: @Kosh Yeah, I think you're right to want to avoid that.... I tried to come up with something better, but so far nothing comes to mind. Good luck! Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Thanks to you, Cronus!

Comment: @Kosh Sure thing... Here's a very rough idea that might be useful: perhaps one can prove there is some huge open ball which contains $K$ and whose intersection with $\Omega$ is still connected (and necessarily open). Then it is enough to cover this intersection with linked balls (which are contained inside it). And maybe this would be a little easier. But I'm not sure, it's just an idea.

Comment: Hi Cronus, I think that to prove this result, one has to go through the following two steps. First, one has to show the result when $K$ is the trace $\Gamma$ of a smooth curve, and the open set is $\Gamma + B_\epsilon$ where $B_\epsilon$ is the ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at the origin. Then one has to prove that for every compact set $K$ in $\Omega$ there exists a smooth curve $\Gamma$ whose tubular neighborhood $\Gamma + B_\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ sufficiently small contains $K$ and is contained in $\Omega$. At least, that is the path I will try if no one answers.

Comment: @Kosh Yeah this could work. Although I'm not sure it would not result in even more technical details than the first idea you mentioned/a "snake" construction. Good luck :)